# how to log statements that execute on an index in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have an index for a table in oracle and I don't know it is being used or not and how it is used. Is there a way to log all statements that uses that index? If not is there a way to know if that index is being used or not?

Thanks,

Comment: What is your ultimate goal, i.e. why do you want to do this? Are you  trying to work out which indexes are used and which not? As if you have a lot going on in your DB you may have to do some really nasty stuff to answer your question and there might be easier ways to go about it.

Comment: Ultimately i need to know if i can remove a certain indexes on my table or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding the ultimate goal would definitely be helpful.

You can query the `GV$SQL_PLAN` table to see which queries in the shared pool are using a particular index

```
SELECT *
  FROM gv$sql_plan
 WHERE object_owner = <<owner of object>
   AND object_name  = <<name of index>>
```

Depending on your system, however, SQL statements may not stay in the shared pool particularly long so you may need to poll relatively frequently to ensure you don't miss anything.  Depending on the Oracle version, edition, and licensed options, you may also be able to query the AWR tables to get historical plan information.  But that will only have information on queries that were sufficiently expensive that they were captured in an AWR snapshot.

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_hist_sql_plan
 WHERE object_owner = <<owner of object>
   AND object_name  = <<name of index>>
```

If what you are trying to accomplish is to figure out whether an index is being used, however, you probably want to use something like [index monitoring](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/IndexMonitoring.php) and let Oracle track which indexes are being used.  Be aware, however, that there are pitfalls to this approach.  For example [indexes on foreign keys](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2008/09/12/index-monitoring-and-foreign-keys-caution-kid-a/) that are necessary for efficient deletes may not be flagged as being used by index monitoring (nor will they be caught by just looking at query plans).  Index monitoring may also miss cases where [statistics on an index are used](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/category/index-monitoring/) to come up with an efficient plan despite the index itself not being used.

Comment: If my ultimate goal is to drop an index w/o impacting production, is there another tool that give me that information?

Comment: @SeanNguyen - First off, be aware that even if no statement ever uses a particular index, that doesn't necessarily imply that you can drop it without risk.  It's possible that the statistics on the index (or statistics on the column that are gathered because the column is indexed).  You can potentially use index monitoring (updated my answer) but there are pitfalls.

Comment: My index is a spatial index. It doesn't look like i can monitor domain index. Here is an error: SQL Error: ORA-29871: invalid alter option for a domain index